# Simple Employee Asset Software

Tags: hardware, tracking, asset-management

We need software that will let us quickly assign items to users, and see what users have already been assigned. We don't need to track individual items, but, for instance, we need to see that a user has been given a charger, when it was given, if it has been returned. We deal with employees who may ask for replacement parts, and some who might want to borrow parts, and it is a very one directional flow of equipment.

Just need to be able to track if users have been given generic pieces of equipment, really. I have not been able to find a solution that puts emphasis on the user instead of the equipment, since we are talking about unimportant pieces like cables and mice.

Typing (item names) would be okay, though we have always found consistency to be a pain, and the items we would look to deploy would be generic items that we could preconfigure. Additionally, we are looking simply to be able to see what assets an employee has been given, however, summary tools (e.g.  "What employees have a mouse now?" or "How many mice are lent out there now?") would be useful for budget and SLAs.

Comment: Should the software be usable from several separate computers, or are you OK with forcing everyone to use the same computer when they want to lend a mouse? Is a web UI OK? Do you have a server to host it, or is SaaS OK?

Comment: Do you have a budget, and if yes how much? Also, what OS should it be able to run on? Please edit your question to add all of this information.

Comment: I would be interested in this as well...

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Clappia](https://www.clappia.com?simple-employee-asset-software) for this use case. Clappia is a cloud-based platform that you can use to design custom apps within minutes, and without writing any code. I was able to create this app on Clappia within 5 minutes.

[image: Sample Application]

This can be further customised to pick up the list of all employees and all assets from a database or an excel. You can then track the assets based on multiple filters as shown below.

[image: View issues]

In the screenshot there are columns named "Asset", "Employee", "Assigned Date". Filters can be applied to any of these columns (Although screenshot shows filters only on Date and status, it is configurable). So if you want to track all assets issued to "John", you can do that by configuring a filter on the "Employee" column.

You can also assign one of multiple statuses to each submission like "ISSUED", "RETURNED", "LOST".

Disclosure: I am associated with Clappia.